# Very long timescale stress relief in glass

Tags: material-science, glass

If someone scratches a glass, it is becoming weaker at this point, and more prone to cracking.
But with time (tens and hundreds of years ) glass looses its shape because glass has amorphous structure. My question is: are these weak points introduced by scratching becoming less “weak” with time, or maybe at some time they completely go away?
Here is an example of what I ask, let’s say someone needs to cut a glass, and makes a scratch with a glass cutter; but then he leaves the glass untouched for 10 years or maybe 100 years. Is glass going to have this weak spot still present after a significant time passed?
A side question is this timeframe could be reduced with minor heating to the temperatures smaller than the reannealing temperatures?

So basically I’m interested in low temperature reannealling (at ambient temperatures and at temperatures < 200 C).

Comment: Some resources that may help inform an answer: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0022309322005014 https://www.osti.gov/biblio/10141853 https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0022309323000431 https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022309314006152?casa_token=cTQBR30DZI0AAAAA:tPCzDGvZ8hmqIG_62IQefUYfXqah8KQ6E5PaeBNPgM-_xX-ruziqFqa3PVcZeMdbb4m3CN-lGg

Comment: Consider also Engineering Stack Exchange.